How to handle exceptions in Apache Beam (python), for reading from JDBC and writing to BigQuery
I was able to successfully read from JDBC source, and write the output back to BigQuery.
However, I'm still stuck in fining the best way to handle BigQuery insert exceptions for bad rows.
For example, the following rows from the JDBC source, the first 2 rows are good ones and no issue inserting into BigQuery. However, third record has a bad datetime, and will cause my code to throw an expectation.



id
email
firstname
lastname
dateofbirth




005a31ba-d16c-42d5
myemail@email.org
jogn
peter
1996-07-01 00:00:00


007705f9-e248-492c
myemail@email.org
jogn
peter
2000-09-15 00:00:00


042c5001-077f-4d49
myemail@email.org
jogn
peter
0001-01-01 00:00:00



I was expecting that bad row to be handled in Get Errors and  Write Errors steps in my pipeline where it was supposed to write failed BigQuery rows to dead letter queue table.
I'm getting the following exception :
ERROR:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2024-06-15T15:27:01.408Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/dummy-project/datasets/jdbctests/tables/users/streams/Cig2NmRiZDZhMC0wMDAwLTI5ZDYtYjYzNS1jODJhZGQ2YzQzZTg6czEz failed with Status Code INVALID_ARGUMENT. The stream may not exist.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.finishBundle(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1776)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PTransformFunctionRegistry.lambda$register$0(PTransformFunctionRegistry.java:116)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:560)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/dummy-project/datasets/jdbctests/tables/users/streams/Cig2NmRiZDZhMC0wMDAwLTI5ZDYtYjYzNS1jODJhZGQ2YzQzZTg6czEz failed with Status Code INVALID_ARGUMENT. The stream may not exist.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn$DestinationState.lambda$flush$8(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:778)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.await(RetryManager.java:311)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.flushAll(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:965)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.finishBundle(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:1113)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: **INVALID_ARGUMENT: Timestamp field value is out of range: -62135769600000000 on field dateofbirth.** Entity: projects/dummy-project/datasets/jdbctests/tables/users/streams/Cig2NmRiZDZhMC0wMDAwLTI5ZDYtYjYzNS1jODJhZGQ2YzQzZTg6czEz

Here's my code :
import argparse
import logging
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType, MillisInstant
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import RetryStrategy


users_schema = {
    "fields": [
        {"type": "STRING", "name": "id", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"type": "STRING", "name": "email", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"type": "STRING", "name": "firstname", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"type": "STRING", "name": "lastname", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"type": "TIMESTAMP", "name": "dateofbirth", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    ]
}


error_schema = {
    "fields": [
        {"name": "destination", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"name": "row", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"name": "error_message", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    ]
}


class LogResults(beam.DoFn):
    """Just log the results"""

    def process(self, element):
        logging.info("elment.logger - : %s", element)
        yield element


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, pipeline_type_check=True)
    LogicalType.register_logical_type(MillisInstant)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        users = p | "Read users" >> ReadFromJdbc(
            table_name="users",
            query="SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname, dateofbirth FROM users;",
            driver_class_name="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
            jdbc_url="xxxx",
            username=r"xxxxx",
            password=r"xxxxx",
            classpath=["jdbc/mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar"],
        )

        result = (
            users
            | "map Dict" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x._asdict())
            | "Log users_favfilms" >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())
            | "write users to BQ"
            >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                schema=users_schema,
                table="jdbctests.users",
                method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API,
                insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_NEVER,
            )
        )

        _ = (
            result.failed_rows_with_errors
            | "Get Errors"
            >> beam.Map(
                lambda e: {
                    "destination": e[0],
                    "row": json.dumps(e[1]),
                    "error_message": e[2][0]["message"],
                }
            )
            | "Write Errors"
            >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API,
                table="jdbctests.jdbcerrros",
                schema=error_schema,
                insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_NEVER,
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()

I'd like to be able to handle those bad rows, and avoid interrupting the pipeline, and then process them at later stage.
Any advice or hint would be very appreciated, thank you.

This looks like a bug. Does this work when you using STREAMING_INSERT? STORAGE_WRITE_API calls the Java implementation, which might not capture this error correctly.

thanks Xo, I think I tried and it was the same error. Well, let me re-test again using other BQ APIs and get back to you

I wasn't able to use STREAMING_INSERT due to a bug related to  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317904/apache-beam-python-sdk-reading-from-postgres-using-jdbc-io) and (https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28359)

https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28359#issuecomment-1711874721 the workaround doesn't work for you?

yes, unfortunately. Using that workaround won't work with STREAM_API and I keep getting >> "return Timestamp(seconds=int(value.seconds), micros=int(value.micros))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

So I think the issue here is the exact error you produce.
ERROR:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2024-06-15T15:27:01.408Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/dummy-project/datasets/jdbctests/tables/users/streams/Cig2NmRiZDZhMC0wMDAwLTI5ZDYtYjYzNS1jODJhZGQ2YzQzZTg6czEz failed with Status Code INVALID_ARGUMENT. The stream may not exist

Seems like you are trying to write to non-existent dummy-project.
We write records to DLQ when certain valid failures occur when writing to BQ. Basically, we check the underlying channel for failures to BQ when writing and if BQ reported an error we write such records to DLQ. For other more catastrophic failures, we just fail the pipeline (so your records will never be lost).
In this case, the write to DLQ happens here.
Since you were trying to write to an non-existent project, this ended up being a more catastrophic failure (we couldn't create the channel at all). Hence the pipeline failed instead of writing failed records to BQ.

thanks Chamikrara for you inputs, but I can confirm that the project exists and it's nothing to do with the project existing. The code will run without issues if I eliminate the faulty row.

Thanks for the clarification. Looking deeper into the code, seems like we intentially raise a RunTimeException here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/cfbcdf03906f0ffe3553b94f391c566eeed8b2fe/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java#L770

I think the current intention of the connector is to write actual errors from BQ to the DLQ (not RuntimeExceptions raised at the client side) but probably we should clarify this in the documentation.

Thank you Chamikara for the clarification, I understand it now. Do you have suggestion/tips  for me how to handle those Runtime Exceptions in code?
